# Поле NULL в MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, погуглил, что-то не нашел похожих вопросов как у меня. Делаю небольшой сайтик, он подразумевает, что там будут пользователи, у которых в профиле будет их аватарка и описание. Сейчас продумываю базу данных, и вот возник вопрос - есть два поля соответственно типа ava и opisanie. У пользователя они могут быть не заполнены (тогда поставится дефолтная аватарка-заглушка и не будет описания). Так вот - мне оставлять в бд для строчек параметр NOT NULL или поставить NULL? Чем они в данном случае принципиально отличаться будут, и в дальшнейшем если пользователь выберет аву, например, ссылку в ava посредством update я смогу запихать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

да сможете обновить. просто если поле нулл, то и возвращаять будет нулл, если не нулл, то возвращать будет то, что вы зададите для этого поля поумолчанию.

Comment: То есть если сделать СЕЛЕКТ * тратата и смотреть на результат, то если я ничего не указал в поле ava, то это поле будет равно NULL. И если через эхо, к примеру, выводить там типа $query['ava'], то будет писаться NULL?  
Но если значение поставить NOT NULL в бд, то если поле ava будет пустое, то и какое-нибудь эхо ничего не выведет, я правильно понял?

Comment: оно будет просто пустое.  
если not null, то обычно задается какоето значение поумолчанию.

Comment: Спасибо. Хотя помню в другом сайте вроде не было условий для NOT NULL, и строчки тоже пустые выдавались. В чем тогда различие? Собственно, поэтому и спросил:)

Comment: ну за других говорить не могу, но для меня если not null значит ЧТОТО должно быть :) иначе оно null :)